# Draw and Color Overlapping Circles with Shapely in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapely

I am trying to draw and color overlapping circles using Shapely in Python. I've looked at several similar examples but keep running into problems with depreciated functions (like cascaded_union)

Here's my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon



def plot_coords(coords):
    pts = list(coords)
    x, y = zip(*pts)
    plt.plot(x,y)


def plot_polys(polys):
    for poly in polys:
        plot_coords(poly.exterior.coords)

points = [Point(0, 0),
             Point(2,0),
             Point(1,2),
             Point(-1,2),
             Point(-2,0),
             Point(-1,-2),
             Point(1,-2)]

for point in points:
    plot_polys([point.buffer(2.2)])
    
plt.show()
```

The output looks like so:

[image]

From here, I would like to fill in the circles with colors I choose. I want the overlapping areas to have mixed colors, but to do this I need to figure out how to define the overlap. I tried following along [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187402/how-to-find-the-intersection-areas-of-overlapping-buffer-zones-in-single-shapefi/187499#187499) with unary_union, but I am a bit lost how to do this on a series of buffered points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm also open to other methods of accomplishing this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe a step towards a solution, you can try the matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between methods for your circles and use the alpha argument to have different colors in overlying sections.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon

def plot_coords(coords, col):
    pts = list(coords)
    x, y = zip(*pts)
    plt.plot(x, y, c=col)


def plot_polys(polys, col):
    for poly in polys:
        plot_coords(poly.exterior.coords, col=col)
        # the line I added
        plt.fill_between(*poly.exterior.xy, alpha=.5, facecolor=col, edgecolor=None)


# define list of colors
colors = ['r', 'r', 'r', 'k', 'k', 'k', 'g', 'g']

# convert list to generator for easy iteration in loop
color_gen = (col for col in colors)


points = [Point(0, 0),
          Point(2, 0),
          Point(1, 2),
          Point(-1, 2),
          Point(-2, 0),
          Point(-1, -2),
          Point(1, -2)]

for point in points:
    plot_polys([point.buffer(2.2)], col=next(color_gen))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great step, thanks! Do you happen to have any idea how I could pick the colors for each segment, or do you think I should post that as a new question? Thanks again!

Comment: i edited my answer, but i was not entirely sure what you meant by 'segment'. in the edited version the colors of the circles can be assigned

Comment: this is very helpful! Any chance you know what those pesky straight lines are doing near y = 0, x = 1ish, and x = 3ish?

Comment: jup, happens when plt.fill_between() tries to draw edges (I never found out why). i edited the solution, facecolor and edgecolor now have to be defined separately, but the lines disappear when edgecolor is set as None